# An $\ell_p$ inequality for discrete martingales

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

If $Y_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a martingale, where $X_i$ is a martingale difference sequence, $\mathbb{E}[X_n\mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]=0$ for all $n$, we know that
$$ \mathbb{E}\big[Y_n^2-Y_{n-1}^2\big]=\mathbb{E}X_n^2,$$
by using the simple fact that $Y_n^2=Y_{n-1}^2+2X_nY_{n-1}+X_n^2$, where the cross term vanishes since $Y_{n-1}$ is $\mathcal F_{n-1}$ measurable and $X_i$ centred, that is,
$$ \mathbb{E}[X_nY_{n-1}]=\mathbb{E}\big[Y_{n-1}\mathbb{E}[X_n\mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]\big] =0.$$
A similar property, but now as an inequality, holds if we replace the square with the absolute value,
$$ \mathbb{E}\big[|Y_n|-|Y_{n-1}|\big]\le\mathbb{E}|X_n|.$$
Does something analogous hold for other powers? Namely, something along the lines of
$$ \mathbb{E}\big[|Y_n|^r-|Y_{n-1}|^r\big]\le C\mathbb{E}|X_n|^r,$$
for $1<r<2$ and some $C>0$?

Comment: Is $X_i$ supposed to be a martingale, or is $Y_n$ supposed to be the martingale?  In general, $\mathbb{E}[X_n|\mathcal F_{n-1}] = 0$ doesn't hold for martingales.

Comment: Yes I was a bit imprecise. $X_i$ is supposed to be an MDS. I edited the question to reflect the change

Answer (score 4):

The question was affirmatively [answered](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407592/inequality-for-increments-of-rth-absolute-moments-of-martingales-1r2) on mathoverflow. Specifically, applying inequality (1.1) in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-functional-analysis/volume-6/issue-4/Best-possible-bounds-of-the-von-Bahr--Esseen-type/10.15352/afa/06-4-1.full) (DOI: 10.15352/afa/06-4-1) with $n=2$ yields
$$ \mathbb{E}[|Y_n|^r] \le \mathbb{E}[|Y_{n-1}|^r]+C_r\mathbb{E}[|X_n|^r], $$
where $1\le C_r\le 2$. The paper states that an inequality of this types holds not just for the power function $\lvert \cdot\lvert^r$, but for a certain class of generalised moment functions, where the corresponding constant depends on the moment function.

Comment: Sorry, this was the first question I asked, so I'm not sure what should I do now. Should I mark it as answered (which felt odd since I wrote it), or should I do something else?